# php change specific characters to html tags

Tags: php, html, database, parsing, mediawiki

I have some text data stored in my database, and I want it to be displayed in an specific way: I store the data followind wikipedia standard, for example:

```
==title==
some ''data''
```

And I want this data to be translated to `<b>`, `<h2>`, `<i>`, etc.
Is there any function/parser to easily achive this?

Comment: Are you trying to have it parsed like markdown?

Comment: @JoshStrange: This MediaWiki's text markup, it is not Markdown.

Comment: DId not knew about markdown, I'll have a look at it also, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are numerous libraries for parsing and rendering MediaWiki markup, including some written in PHP.  See http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers

Comment: +1 for giving correct solution as opposed to others' solutions.

Answer (score -2):

PHP's `str_replace($search, $replace, $subject)` function can take arrays as parameters, and replaces each occurence of $search's elements in $subject with the respective element of $replace.
See http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: First of all, I was looking for something allready defined. Moreover, the same characters may be transformed to different characters. For example, the first == will be translated to <h1> and the second to </h1>.

Comment: -1 for giving solution that does not even work in the example case. For example `==title==` should be changed into `<h2>title</h2>`, not into `<h2>title<h2>` or `</h2>title</h2>`, thus your solution would create incorrect HTML (at least).

Comment: There are ways around that even using `str_replace()`, and if that isn't enough `preg_replace()` can achieved that and much, much more.

Comment: Just don't. Bill's answer is the right way to go on about this, and your solution doesn't even work according to what was requested.

Comment: Bill's solution is definitely the right one, it just wasn't immediately apparent (to me at least), before edits, that he just wanted to handle MediaWiki-style markup.